# Screen error of missing lines and blurred fonts in Win7?

Tags: graphics-card, display, fonts, resolution, lcd

I want to have Windows 7 running on a 1440p LCD with AMD 7850 DVI, and 1/3 horizontal lines are completely invisible.

I have adjusted ClearType many times, changed the DPI to different settings, and tried XP DPI mode. Because it's actual lines vanishing, it seems more serious than a ClearType issue?

Here is an example of the error for Windows Paint: I draw straight lines downwards, and the lines look dotted because some of the lines are completely hidden.
[image]

What's going on and how can I fix it?

Comment: Are you 100% sure the display is set to the native resolution? Is it fully digital DVI, or are you using a VGA adapter? And... DPI & ClearType are about font rendering, why do you think changing those would affect Paint drawings?

Comment: its a 2560-1440p LCD, Auto-detected by windows, so resolution is written the same. DVI is digital from the graphics card to the LCD input. I started by seeing the font errors so I tried to fix them, and I found the error in Windows paint just now, the | cursor was vanishing every 2-3 spaces.

Answer (score 0):

Some monitors are not as precise with DVI as they are with HDMI.

I switched to HDMI, which runs completely perfect.